# How to turn off "Enhance audio" permanently?

Tags: windows, audio, windows-11

Bluetooth headphones have "Enhance audio" enabled every time they connect.
This setting causes the sound to have some reverberation (not sure how best to describe it!) but I turn if off every time.
Is there any way to do this permanently?

[image: Windows 11 Sound Settings]

The same effect is achieved by "Disable all enhancements" but checking this box is also not permanent.

[image]

Comment: I wonder if, while the headphones are connected, find them in the Device Manager, right-click, Properties, Driver tab, Driver Details button, and try to find some related attribute that can be disabled.

Comment: Wasn't able to find anything in Driver Details. I've updated the question with some more info.

Comment: Did you find maybe something related to the 3 enhancements under the "Disable all enhancements"? What is your driver?

Comment: It's a wild shot, but try to rename your headphones (link visible in your first image). It might cause the setting to get stuck in the registry.

Comment: @1NN Tried renaming but when I disconnect and re-connect the name disappears